autodiscover_tasks is not working in Celery with Python
I am trying to figure out good way to register the tasks in Celery. I am using pure python and celery. I don't want to use the include or register method. Instead of that I created the separate directory for tasks with below structure.
main.py
config.py
tasks
  __init__.py
  add.py

So now I can specify the tasks folder as module in autodiscover_tasks. But it's throwing error as No module named 'tasks'
**main.py**
from celery import Celery

app = Celery('celery_proj')

app.config_from_object('config')

app.autodiscover_tasks(['tasks'])

app.conf.update(
    task_acks_late=True,
    worker_prefetch_multiplier=1,
    worker_heartbeat=120,
    result_expires=3600,
)

def get_app():
    return app



add.py
from celery import Task,app

class TaskGeneral(Task):
    def on_failure(self, exc, task_id, args, kwargs, einfo):
        print('{0!r} failed: {1!r}'.format(task_id, exc))

    def on_success(self, retval, task_id, args, kwargs):
        print('{0!r} succeed: {1!r}'.format(task_id, retval))

@app.task(name='celery_proj.tasks.add.add', base=TaskGeneral)
def add(x, y):
    return x + y

config.py
broker_url = 'redis://localhost:6379/0'
result_backend = 'redis://localhost:6379/0'

I want to know what mistake I am making and I need suggestion for the good practice like how to register the task dynamically instead of manual one.


I want to know the clear idea of good way to handle the celery when we have a long running tasks. How to register those properly


Did you find the solution?
